# NodeJs - date format changes when assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, date

i've this code below and the output. any idea why does this happen and how to keep the date as is when assigned.

```
// y is fetched from mysql database
console.log(y); => result (2019-07-10T02:30:00.000Z)
x += y +" ";
console.log(x); => result (Wed Jul 10 2019 05:30:00 GMT+0300 (Arabian Standard Time))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my understanding, that happens because JS uses the `toString()` method of the Date Object when you do a string related operation with it.

So instead of just concatenating it, convert it to ISO format and then concatenate.

`x += y.toISOString() +" ";`

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because JavaScript runtime engine automatically detects the date datatype when value is updated in line #3. At run time it takes the locale settings of the machine on which the JavaScript code is executed and it formats the date based on locale & regional settings.

Comment: The Date is not formatted based on locale, but on the format specified by [*ECMA-262 Date.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring). Only the timezone offset comes from the host, the name of the timezone is optional and implementation dependant.